# Data copying from USB flash drive on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, flash

Due to an accident, a very important USB flash drive was inserted into an Ubuntu computer with personal files.

Is it possible in any kind of way that the computer copied and saved files from the USB drive, even though the files were not opened?c

Can the computer scan the files and keep them somehow?

If yes, should I delete the computer?

If the computer was online can someone take the files from the USB without me knowing?

Answer (score 0):

If you inserted the USB into the computer and you were the only person using that computer at the time, didn't copy any data off it and then removed the USB and left, then you're safe.

However, if you left the USB in the computer say overnight, where other people may have had access to it, then there's no way to tell, you can find out the last time the computer was plugged into a usb port, but to my knowledge and [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146351/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-when-a-usb-flash-drive-has-been-last-used-on-any-com) there is no way to tell if data has been taken off it.

Comment: but the computer was connected online, maybe some software copied it automatically and sent it to some hacker?

Comment: @GerogeH Yeah it is. I wrote a `vbs` to silently steal files from inserted flash drives on Windows. It's also possible that a simple shell script does the same thing in a Unix system.